# Write text to a buffer in memory in swi-prolog?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

This is pretty much what I'm trying to achieve.

```
process(P,Txt) :- 
    % do stuff and write messages to Txt, but not to std out.

start(P) :-
    process(P,Txt),
    write(Txt).   % now write to std out.
```

Can I do this with SWI-Prolog? Is there a way to write text to a stream in memory, and output that text later?

Comment: Loon into the SWI-Prolog section on memory files: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=memory-files

Comment: Great, thanks. Can you write this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWI-Prolog provides some non-standard but quite useful features that can help you in your task. One of them are memory files, which can be used for temporary buffering of data. For details see:

http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=memory-files

Another option could be to use the `with_output_to/2` built-in predicate that allows you to write to e.g. and atom or a string that you can later output:

http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=with_output_to/2